# Route NotFoundHttpException after prefix with locale in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In Laravel 5.4 I want to prefix locale with base url.When i run php artisan serve then i get

> notfoundhttpexception

. It does work if i put manually http://localhost:8000/en. what i want now, when i will run php artisan serve it should redirect to http://localhost:8000/en.

Following is the route file:

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => App::getLocale() ], function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home.index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem properly, You need use code like this:

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => '{locale}' ], function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home.index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));
    //Setup locale based on request...
    App::setLocale(Request::segment(1));
});
```

But the better way I can suggest is use locale setup like:

```
if (in_array(Request::segment(1), ['en', 'fr'])) {
    App::setLocale(Request::segment(1));
} else {
    // set your default local if request having other then en OR fr
    App::setLocale('en');
}
```

And just call route like:

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => '{locale}' ], function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home.index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));
});
```

By this code you can setup locale based on route prefix dynamically.